# Custom circle copper fill in Proteus ARES

Tags: pcb-design, proteus, pcb-layers

My work needs to design a custom circle like in the picture below.

[image]

I need to copper-fill the portion inbetween the two circles. I've tried zone select mode, but it doesn't work efficiently as I need. Is there any option to do it?

Comment: I do not know how to do this in Proteus, however in Eagle one can easily draw a circle with a specific radius and adjust the width of the trace. This results in  the requested shape (like a donut)

Comment: Thanks for the info bro, I'll try in proteus little more.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Circle Touchpad]

I did it like this (2D Graphic circle mode) in combination with (Zone mode) in this case the pad zone is defined as compatible and the outer zone is defined as solid 4 arcs make a part circle outer-edge in my case.

You can use (Zone mode) /-solid- to fill space in between circles as long as you increase the (2D Graphic circle mode) /-width- to cover the edge of (Zone mode) /-Boundary-, also you can thicken and dilute the grid with F2 F3 F4 keys and manipulate the vertexes in such a way that they stay inside the circle boundary.

Answer (score 0):

[image: I did it like below]

I drew multiple circles within the limits to fill it up.